# Get part of script run directory in bash

Tags: bash, path, string-manipulation

I'm running a Bash script that's buried in a directory on my system. I need to be able to get the first section of the directory path.

The path returned by `$0` in my script is as below. The "path/to/script" section is constant; the "/variable/path/to/folder" is permanent.

```
/variable/path/to/folder/main-folder/path/to/my-script.sh
------------------------
```

I need the underlined section. I've tried `cut -d/ -f-4` and `cut -d/ -f4-`, but `cut` indexes from the front of the path, and I need to index from the back. (I don't know how many levels will be between `/` and `main-folder`, but I do know how many will be between `main-folder` and `my-script.sh`. The path here is accurate: there are two folders in `main-folder` before you get to `my-script.sh`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
echo ${0%/*/*/*/*}
```

Comment: I added an extra `*/` to get exactly what I wanted. (I.e., `THINGY=${0%*/*/*/*/*}`.) Can you explain why this works? I've not seen this construct before.

Comment: It's a form of bash parameter expansion. The characters following the `%` are a pattern just as in pathname expansion. If that pattern matches some part of the expansion of the parameter ($0 in this case) from the right, the value of the expression is the expansion of the parameter with the matching part removed. The official explanation can be found in the bash(1) man page. Search for the section on "Parameter Expansion" and look for `${parameter%word}`.